# i want to know the probabillity of exchange

Tags: probability

Very intelligent sisters Deepa and Tara are expecting a fat gift from their
parents for Christmas. Parents have told them that the amount will be a
power of 2 which is at least $32$ and at most $1024$. Parents tell them that
from the set $C= \{5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ either one of the two elements sets $(5,6)$
or $(6,7)$ or $(7,8)$ or $(8,9)$ or $(9,10)$ will be selected at random and in case
$(k,k + 1)$ were selected then two sealed envelops one with a gift check for
$2^k$ and another with a gift check for $2^{k+1}$ will be enclosed and randomly
one will be given to Deepa and another to Tara. Each one can only see the
value of the gift check in their envelop and decide to keep it or exchange
it with sister’s envelop. When one wants to exchange that person should
pay $1$ to parents as fee for facilitating this deal whether her sister agrees
for exchange or not. However exchange can take place only when the sister agrees. Suppose Deepa finds that she has an envelop containing a gift
check for $256$, what will be her expectation if she proposes to exchange
her’s with Tara’s. Do you believe any exchange will take place?
(Hint: Do you think Tara will agree?)

Answer (score 1):

If Deepa gets a check for $256$ that means that Tara, with equal probability of $\frac{1}{2}$, either has a check for $128$ (set (7,8) was chosen) or $512$ (set (8,9) was chosen). Therefore, Deepa's expectation will be $\frac{128+512}{2}-1=319$ which is higher than what she has now so she will ask for the trade.

If Tara has a check for $512$, she will reject the trade because either Deepa has $256$ or $1024$. If Deepa had $1024$, she would not have proposed the trade, so Deepa must have $256$ and Tara should reject.

If Tara has a check for $128$, she will accept the trade because either Deepa has $64$ or $256$ and accepting the trade will give her an expectation of $\frac{64+256}{2}=160$ which is higher than what she has now.